# The image doesn't fill automatically when i zoom in the grid

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, grid

I am facing the problem of images not autofilling when in the end, can you give me a solution to solve the above problem? I am trying to create two rows and two columns: but the problem is when I click on the last image or the last image the problem occurs please see the image below:
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Pdse.png) 

I want if I click the last or last picture it will always stay in this position this is my temporary solution if you have a better solution!
[desire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69aGa.png)

All my source code is [here](https://github.com/hngovan/gan_ring_poc) or you can check out the website here [demo](http://160.16.92.212/)